# Running a Job from a Stored Procedure in another server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, jobs

How can I run a job from another server using a stored procedure?

Let's say

- server 1 : db1
- server 2 : db2
- username : testssis
- password : testssispass
- sqljob found in db2: job1

Here is the part im lost with how can I make this work?

```
xp_cmdshell + osql command -U: -P: + sp_startjob
```

Comment: possible the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573227/how-to-run-a-job-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-server?rq=1) question

Comment: Certainly does seem like a duplicate. to me, Rad's answer seems superior to Timbo's. Using osql and xp_cmdshell seems brittle and may lead to security problems (hardcoded, cleartext passwords).

Answer (score 6):

With a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) - much more reliable and secure than `xp_cmdshell`:

```
EXEC Server2.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'Job2';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have the Sql job in a stored Procedure in server B. Add server B as linked server to Server A, Execute the stored Procedure from server A:

```
EXEC [RemoteServer].DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a small SSIS Package that executes the Procedure.
Deploy the Project to your Agent Server.
Execute the Package using an Agent Job Step.

My use case:  I had a Procedure to prune the tail of a large database of event records and wanted to be sure that it would not interfere with writing to the Head.
I made sure the deletion Procedure would halt itself after a short time window, then added an Agent step to follow after the one that writes to the Head.